# Deleting from beginning of a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This is my code for deleting from beginning of a linked list that contains student record.

```
    int delete (struct student **q) {
        struct student *current;
        current=(struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
        current=head;
        head=current->link;
        free(current);
        //display(current);
        return 1;
    }
```

This is the structure

```
struct student
{
    int id;
    char name[10];
    char gender[10];
    struct student * link;
}*head;
```

But instead of deleting the entire record 
only the id is changed to 0

```
before deletion
  ID       Name Gender
   1    Yazhini Female 
   2        Anu Female 
   3     Janavi Female 
   4    Haritha Female
```

after deletion

```
  ID       Name Gender
   0    Yazhini Female 
   2        Anu Female 
   3     Janavi Female 
   4    Haritha Female
```

Comment: `deletig`...what is that?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @aish  Ignore the reference provided by Sourav Ghosh . It is an answer of a low--qualified programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function can look the following way

```
int delete( struct student **head ) 
{
    int success = *head != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        struct student *current = *head;
        *head = current->link;
        free( current );
    }

    return success;
}
```

As for your function then it has at least a memory leak because at first a memory for a node is allocated and its address is assigned to the variable current

```
current=(struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
```

and then this variable is reassigned.

```
current=head;
```

Also it is not clear what the parameter q means.

Comment: this works..thank u soo much @vlad